# Firebase Hosting Issue: only 2 Files upload (used to be 73 Files, of create-react-app, before using Cloud Function Rewrite)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I want help with an issue probably because of Firebase Hosting as I mention below.

**TOC**

- Question
- What I want to do
- Issue Case
- Key Facts

  - Output
  - Input
- Project Information

  - Technology Version
  - Production URL
  - Basic HTTP Authentication pass
  - GitHub Repository/This Issue Branch
- Folder Structure
- Picture (codes)

  - Root/ firebase.json & .firebaserc
  - Root/functions/ package.json & index.js

...

**Question**

Q. What do you think the cause? (please let me know any probable suspicious  technical facts or something)

- I assume Firebase Hosting is the cause (as I mentioned in "Key Facts/Output" section, Firebase Cloud Function Rewrite is working fine.)

Q. Is it can be the cause that I might have MULTIPLE Node and npm?

- Versions are fine accessing from the project root CLI, but in MacBook root CLI, I have other versions in my MacBook Storage  (as I mention in "Project Information/Technology Version" section)?

Q. Why are Static contents (Root/main-site/build) Responded from the Cloud Function (In Root/functions/index.js) through Firebase Rewrite NOT shown but "Not found"?

- The Cloud Function and Firebase Hosting Rewrite are working fine. (As I mentioned in "Key Facts").

Q. How can I achieve "What I want to do" below?

**What I want to do**

- Users access to the Public URL

  -> Basic HTTP Authentication (npm basic-authentication Package) is shown

  -> (IF if the "user" and "passowrd" are right) Cloud Function Respond with the Static Folder (Root/main-site/build).

**Issue case**

- The Firebase Hosting and Public URL don't work (work in Local Server).

  - Access to the Production URL (https://tyukyu-ex.web.app/)

    -> Enter right Basic HTTP Authentication pass (user & password)

    -> Success

    - UI

      - Only "Not Found"
    - DevTools/Console

      - Error Message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
- The Firebase Console/Hosting page has only 2 Files (used to be 73 before using Cloud Function Rewrite)

**Key Facts**

Output

- The Firebase Rewrites (based on Root/firebase.json) is working & The Cloud Function (functions/) is working well.

  ```
    => The matter of Firebase Hosting. 

    Pro
    : In Local Server, the Basic HTTP Authentication.

    : In Public URL, "Site from Cloud Function/app"  is shown if I Response with res.send("Site from Cloud Function/app") from Cloud Function,
  ```

Input

Firebase

```
- I assume firebase.json is fine (in Pic 1)

  - Set "public": "dummy-public"
 
    * dummy-public/ is empty


- In Root/functions/package.json, Node.js version for Cloud Function is set as "node": "14" (From CLI, says 14.17.1).
```

React

```
- In Root/main-site/.env, I set the PUBLIC_URL=https://tyukyu-ex.web.app
```

**Project Information**

Technology Version

- In the project root directory (tyukyu-ex/)
- Although the versions would be fine in the project root directory, I have other versions in my MacBook Storage(which has the famous Access Permission issue & which I do not know how to safely deal with like deleting).

  `npm -v   7.18.1`

  ```
    * (Latest)
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm
        7.18.1
  ```

  `firebase -v  9.14.0`

  ```
    * (Latest)
    : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools
        9.14.0
  ```

  `node -v  v14.17.1`

  ```
    * (Latest LTS Version)
    : https://nodejs.org/en/download/
        14.17.1
  ```

Production URL

: https://tyukyu-ex.web.app/

Basic HTTP Authentication pass

: Username = user

: Password = password

GitHub Repository/This Issue Branch

: https://github.com/Nobu-sai/shogo-log-tyukyu-ex/tree/issue%3Dfirebase-hosting-not-showing-contents

**Folder Structure**

tyukyu-ex/

```
functions/

main-site/

....
```

**Picture**

[Root/ firebase.json & .firebaserc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8P8Q.png)

[Root/functions/ package.json & index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YkVZ.png)
...

Please feel free to let me know to share something further.
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add meta-commentary to your question nor meta-tags to your title.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions should be limited to one question per; otherwise answers get very long and convoluted. Please update your question with just one question, and clarify what's being asked. These two guides will help you write good questions so please review them [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)